# ASP.NET Core - Azure Active directory Authentication - Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2, microsoft-identity-web

I have a .NET Core 2.2 / Angular 10 app where I want to implement an Azure AD login. The app already has a simple user/password login using JWT:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer("Default",options=>
....
  options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["SecurityKeyIssuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["SecurityKeyAudience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["SecurityKey"]))
            };
```

Now I tried adding this:

```
 .AddJwtBearer("AzureAD",opt =>
        {
            opt.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
            opt.Authority = Configuration["ActiveDirectory:Authority"];
            opt.Audience = Configuration["ActiveDirectory:Audience"];
...
 
services
        .AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Default", "AzureAD")
                .Build();
        });
```

I tried several variations of this, like hardcoding the authority etc. in different formats. I get to the login page where I'm able to log in using the default user/password authentication, but after that every page only shows me this 500 error:

[image]

Even after I commented out all the new configs. When I remove the AzureAD authentication scheme, it works normally again.
Any suggestions?

Of course I registered the app and used the info from the Azure AD page.

Also, when trying this:

```
services.AddAuthentication("MyAuthenticationScheme")
      .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp();
```

It says:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1061  'AuthenticationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp' and no accessible extension method 'AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp' accepting a first argument of type 'AuthenticationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  JI.Infopool.WebApp  C:\Projekte\JI.Infopool - master\JI.Infopool.WebApp\Startup.cs  56  Active

Although I've included the NuGet Package Microsoft.Identity.Web

Answer (score 0):

1.Initially please check if the login request to microsoft was locked by the firewall.

2.Make sure  `appsettings.json` values are correct.

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "<azure ad domain>",
  "TenantId": "<azure ad tenant id>",
  "ClientId": "<backend app id>"
}
```

In Startup.cs

Check the following  code in `ConfigureServices()`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.AddControllersWithViews();
///
//
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd");
        services.AddAuthorization();

        ...
    }
```

In `configure()` method make sure you have these

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
```

Reference: [using openidconnect-with-azure-ad-angular and core webapiconfiguration](https://anthonygiretti.com/2018/02/28/using-openidconnect-with-azure-ad-angular5-and-webapi-core-webapi-configuration/)